# Setup GCDS (Google Cloud Directory Sync) via terminal

Tags: linux, rhel, google-cloud

I have a linux (Centos 7) instance without desktop installed and I need to install and setup Google Cloud Directory Sync services.
I tried to installed it via ssh and it installed successfully but when I tried to run it gives AWT exception (AWT package is used for GUI development in java).

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the linux distribution and his version please ?

1 - Do you have google requirement ?
https://paste.ofcode.org/yRwP9Yc3K8RGY4fWdBfHGx

2 - Your instance can access to google cloud or internet ? 
"The GCDS installer downloads and installs all required components on your server"

3- Can you post your install log ? 
Rq:  https://tools.google.com/dlpage/dirsync

Comment: Updated linux distro in question. Yes my instance is on cloud and it can access internet and the installer provided by google installed successfully. I will update the logs in question.